# How do I apply a rendered attribute to a large block of text?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I can't believe I am asking this after all these months of coding JSF 2.0 pages, but this is the first I have run into this.

I often have an **h:output** tag like this:

```
<h:outputText value="Some sage wisdom" rendered=#{backbean.includeWisdom} style="..." />
```

What tag do I use if the text to conditionally include is large -- like paragraphs long?  I also want to keep the style attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `h:panelGroup` for this purpose.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{backbean.includeWisdom}" style="...">
  Your text 
</h:panelGroup>
```

From the [taglib documentation](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/):

> If the "style" or "styleClass" attributes are present, and the
> "layout" attribute is present with a value of "block", render a "div"
> element, outputting the value of the "style" attribute as the value of
> the "style" attribute and the value of the "styleClass" attribute as
> the value of the "class" attribute.
>
> Otherwise, if the "layout"
> attribute is not present, or the "layout" attribute contains a value
> other than "block", render a "span" element, outputting the value of
> the "style" attribute as the value of the "style" attribute, and the
> value of the "styleClass" attribute as the value of the "class"
> attribute.

Comment: Funny how that didn't occur to me.  I use **panelGroup** all the time to get multiple elements in a table cell.  Thanks for the tip.